# Recognize datetime list

Tags: python

I'm getting data from csv file that contains a column of Datetime.
Datetime are read from csv and insert in a list.

If I want to use this list to plot data in a chart, How can I make the list content recognized as Datetime objects?

This is my csv:

```
DateTime;S1;S2;S3
2020-07-15 16:27:01.221660;652.3826361765446;661.0531016851814;387.24703877989487
2020-07-15 16:27:01.223424;356.3826361765446;243.0531016851814;481.24703877989487
2020-07-15 16:27:01.227896;987.3826361765446;198.0531016851814;275.24703877989487
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

class Read_csv:
    
    
    def csv_reader(self, file_name):
        
        df = pd.read_csv(file_name, delimiter = ';')
        DateTime_array = df["DateTime"].tolist()
        print(DateTime_array)
```

This is the output:

```
['2020-07-15 16:27:01.221660', '2020-07-15 16:27:01.223424', '2020-07-15 16:27:01.227896']
```

Comment: How can I use column name 'DateTime'?

Comment: Would it be possible to cast the entire column to datetime usings `pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? I simply mapped a function to convert every string over all objects of the list.

```
from datetime import datetime

DateTime_array = ['2020-07-15 16:27:01.221660', '2020-07-15 16:27:01.223424', '2020-07-15 16:27:01.227896']

New_DateTime_array = list(map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'), DateTime_array))

print(New_DateTime_array)
#[datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 15, 16, 27, 1, 221660), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 15, 16, 27, 1, 223424), datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 15, 16, 27, 1, 227896)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cast an entire colum to DateTime objects using:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
```

So your code would become:

```
def csv_reader(file_name):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name, delimiter=';')
    df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
    DateTime_array = df["DateTime"].tolist()
    print(DateTime_array)
```

Resulting in:

```
[Timestamp('2020-07-15 16:27:01.221660'), Timestamp('2020-07-15 16:27:01.223424'), Timestamp('2020-07-15 16:27:01.227896')]
```